# Calculate Open Rate (Sum of Engaged / Sum of Nudged) for last 3 weeks at ID level

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Data :

```py
    Id  Year  Week      Nu   En
0    1  2018    21       1        1
1    1  2018    22       1        0
2    1  2018    34       1        1
3    1  2018    35       1        1
4    1  2018    36       1        0
5    1  2018    42       1        0
6    1  2019     2       1        0
7    1  2019     3       1        1
8    1  2019     5       1        1
9    2  2018    40       1        0
10   2  2018    43       1        1
11   2  2018    44       1        1
12   2  2019     2       1        0
13   2  2019     3       1        1
14   3  2018    50       1        1
15   3  2018    52       1        0
16   3  2019     1       1        1
```

Desired output

`Id` level open rate where we need to find last week and calculate open rate 
say for `id` 2 last week is `Year` 2019 `Week` 3.

So to calculate open rate

```py
Id Year   Week      Nu   En

2  2018    43       1        1
2  2018    44       1        1
2  2019     2       1        0
```

Sum of En / Sum of Nu which is (2/3) * 100 = 66.67 %

Comment: Please don't post pictures. The best would be, if you just roll back your last edit- I literally formatted it, so it's better to comprehend for people.

Comment: Ok, now could you be more specific on the logic? It's not really clear for me how did you get on your desired output?

Comment: For Example : For Id 2 in the table we should be obtain the latest week data for that Id and then from there we have to calculate last 3 weeks data excusing the latest week data and obtain the following result like i have already mentioned in the description. Is this clear ?or have to add some more specific data to it

Comment: Yup, fixed below. Let me know, if that's what you're after here?

Comment: Thanks. @Grzegorz it worked 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick - `df` being your input dataframe.

```py
df=df.astype(int) #in case any of the columns is not numeric - this will be a problem later on

df["r"]=df["Year"].mul(100).add(df["Week"])
df["r"]=df.groupby("Id")["r"].rank(ascending=False)
df2=df.loc[df["r"].isin([2,3,4])] #not sure if you actually need to materialize df2 - that's the data frame you're showing in your desired output

df3=df2.groupby("Id")[["Nudged", "Engaged"]].sum()
df3["res"]=df3["Engaged"].div(df3["Nudged"]) #that's the proper final calculation you're looking for
```

Output:

```py
#df2
    Id  Year  Week  Nudged  Engaged    r
5    1  2018    42       1        0  4.0
6    1  2019     2       1        0  3.0
7    1  2019     3       1        1  2.0
10   2  2018    43       1        1  4.0
11   2  2018    44       1        1  3.0
12   2  2019     2       1        0  2.0
14   3  2018    50       1        1  3.0
15   3  2018    52       1        0  2.0
#df3
    Nudged  Engaged       res
Id
1        3        1  0.333333
2        3        2  0.666667
3        2        1  0.500000
```